# C# Richtext Box Selection Remain After Operation

Tags: c#, selection, richtextbox

I'm selecting specific text portion in richtextbox1 and replacing it using regex. After replacing the text, my selection is gone. I want to remain the same selection even after replace. Because I have multiple replaces to do each different ones so I need to remain the selection, otherwise I have to select that specific text again and again. Kindly advise me on this.

```
            string str = richTextBox1.SelectedText;
            int caretIndex = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            int lineNumber = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(caretIndex);
            Point characterXY = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(caretIndex);
            int characterIndex = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(characterXY);
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = Regex.Replace(str, "123", "456");
```

Comment: var newtext = Regex.Replace(...); richTextBox1.SelectedText = newtext; richTextBox1.SelectionStart = caretIndex; richTextBox1.SelectionLength = newtext.Length;

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
        var str = richTextBox1.SelectedText;
        var start = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        var end = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = Regex.Replace(str, "123", "456");
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        richTextBox1.Select(start,end);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, now it's selection remaining like this: Star is fine, end is reaching at end of the richtextbox. It should remain at the end until the selection part only